# Multiple AJAX calls to Bind a section using knock Out

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have an ascx control which contains following code

```
<div class="test" data-bind="template: { name: 'sampleDetailed-template', foreach: viewModel.sampleData.dataList }">
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="'sampleDetailed-template"> 
 <div>No:     <!--ko text: number--><!--/ko--></div>
</script>
```

Currently i am filling sampleData from one ajax call which will return a list of data .for example 100.It will show 100 such Divs.It is working fine.

But now i want to split UI and bind section with different ajax calls(10 calls in above example).ie I will get the 100 Nos in 10 calls.I want to bind the section with 10,then 10 etc....to avoid bulk data issue.

ASCX control is added in page

How can i achieve this using knock out.

Comment: Are you talking about a lazy loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ko.observableArray` supports this out of the box. Whenever you push items to it, the UI will update. The callback for each request will be something like `obsArr(obsArr().concat(newData))`.

Here's an example:

```js
var myData = ko.observableArray([
  { number: 1 },
  { number: 2 },
  { number: 3 },
]);

var loadData = function(newData) {
  var current = myData();  
  
  // Create mock-data for this example
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    current.push({ number: current.length });
  }
  
  myData(current);
  
};
  
ko.applyBindings({viewModel: { sampleData: { dataList: myData } } , load: loadData});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="test" data-bind="template: { name: 'sampleDetailed-template', foreach: viewModel.sampleData.dataList }">
</div>
<button data-bind="click: load">load more</button>

<script type="text/html" id="sampleDetailed-template"> 
 <div>No:     <!--ko text: number--><!--/ko--></div>
</script>
```